# Excel Now Function

Tags: excel

I have function NOW.

Every time I'm input number the function should update the current date and time that the number was insert.

My current situation is that every time that I had a new number - ALL previous inputs change to the current date and time, and I need them to stay as they are (the previous date and time).

What can I do with that?

Comment: You will need to use vba in a worksheet_change event.  formulas are live and will always update.  Using vba the value can be "set" and will not change unless the target range changes.

Comment: Does it work with google sheets?

Comment: If you wan google sheets, why the `excel` tag?  You will need to create the same type of thing with their coding in their events.  They will not be cross compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA Function

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1000")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target(1, 2)
        .Value = Date
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```